# Does link prefetching work across subdomains?

Tags: html, link-prefetch

I've been trying to use something like this to get a performance boost when clicking from a simple landing page to a heavyweight single page app:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com" as="document" />
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/app.js" as="script" />
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/app.css" as="style" />
```

It seems to have no noticeable performance boost when my landing page is on a subdomain. Say, `https://subdomain.example.com`.

When I click on a link to visit `https://example.com`, I still see a long delay in the Chrome network tab as `app.js` and `app.css` are loaded:

[image: Prefetched resources]
[image: Resource download time with prefetching]

Here's the same resource with prefetching disabled:

[image: Resource download time without prefetching]

It takes roughly the same amount of time in total.

---

Request headers for one of the assets that loaded with prefetch cache:

General:

```
Request URL: https://example.com/css/app.bffe365a.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200  (from prefetch cache)
Remote Address: 13.226.219.19:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=31536000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 39682
content-type: text/css
date: Mon, 06 Jan 2020 21:42:53 GMT
etag: "d6f5135674904979a2dfa9dab1d2c440"
last-modified: Mon, 06 Jan 2020 20:46:46 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
via: 1.1 example.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: dO3yiCoPErExrE2BLYbUJaVye32FIJXXxMdI4neDGzGX9a6gcCDumg==
x-amz-cf-pop: LAX50-C1
x-amz-id-2: 1O0LmihxpHIywEaMQWX7G3FDAzxtH9tZq1T/jeVLMzifFSJSIIJSS6+175H61kKdAq6iEbwfs2I=
x-amz-request-id: AF35C178092B65D4
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

Request:

```
DNT: 1
Referer: https://example.com/auth/join
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
```

---

My question is: **If Chrome indicates that the prefetch cache is used then why is there a significant content download time?**

It seems that Chrome has different kinds of caches: prefetch cache, disk cache and memory cache. Disk cache and memory cache are very fast (5ms and 0ms load times). However prefetch cache is pretty useless with 300ms download times sometimes. Can I get a technical explanation of why this happens? Is it a bug with Chrome? I am on Chrome 79.0.3945.117.

Comment: Prefetch is used to speed up future navigations, see a brief explanation from (https://web.dev/link-prefetch/)

Comment: Yes, prefetch should speed up future navigations. Then why didn't it speed it up in my case? See the timing graphs.

Comment: Can you try and place the subdomain contents on another domain and check if that also takes the same time to load? You seem to have drawn that the subdomain might be an issue without showing it by showing how non-subdomain (ie other domain) case works. If the subdomain is an issue then the next step would be to explore if there's a Chrome config setting to tweak that will do this, or

Comment: Or does the same loading times for both subdomain and/or indie domain appear on other browsers with similar toolsets such as Firefox Inspector or Opera? If the same timing issue is occuring on other browsers that use different engines (I'm not sure which do and don't any more) as you reference, it may well be a bug - I can entirely believe it could be a Chrome bug if these noted time values are noticably different on other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess. Confident answer probably can be found only by you, through experiment. There are too much variables to account for. But here some ideas:

1. `prefetch` is a **hint** for a browser. Browser can ignore it for some arbitrary reasons. More than that it has the lowest priority.
2. E.g. just in case, please, check your browser settings:
   `Menu/Settings/Advanced/Privacy and security/Preload pages for faster browsing and searching`
   (or something like that).
3. If by any chance you are using mobile internet it also can be a problem.
   https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-prefetch
4. How fast do you navigate from your landing page to the `example.com`?
5. Check your server logs to see if it ever receives `prefetch` requests.
6. Check if your server sets some strange headers in response to `prefetch` requests. E.g. `Cache-Control: no-cache`. Yea, I see that you have `cache-control: max-age=31536000`, so it would be really strange, if the server will send different header for the same request (well... *almost the same*, at least you did not said that they are, and there at least can be some headers indicating that it is a `prefetch` request), but strange things happen.
7. You probably should try to add `crossorigin` attribute. E.g.

   `<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/app.css" as="style" crossorigin />`

   Here https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/ you can find this example

   ```html
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//example.com">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="//cdn.example.com" crossorigin>
   ```

   quite relevant for your case, but unfortunately with no explanation.
8. In the original version of your question you mentioned service workers... 
   If they download something, or even yourself manually downloading something, it also can be the issue. Because of the lowest priority of `prefetch`

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ#What_if_I.27m_downloading_something_in_the_background.3F_Will_link_prefetching_compete_for_bandwidth.3F

   > If you are downloading something using Mozilla, link prefetching will be delayed until any background downloads complete

   I think same goes for the Chrome.
9. Have you tried to move your landing page to the root domain? If, yes, and `prefetch` works as expected, then yes - subdomain is the cause of issue. And GUI message `Status Code: 200  (from prefetch cache)` is probably just a glitch. Because just recently some things began to change in the `prefetch` behavior in Chrome. And I do not know yet if things settled out. Basically, yes, there is certain probability that you can `prefetch` only from the same origin.

   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bKGDIePAuF6YXmmrwM33LeLvtuCsla3vTspsxsNp-f8/edit

Comment: Some random notes after reading your answer: I navigate very slowly from landing page to example.com, allowing enough time for all resources to load. I did the testing above with service workers disabled in Chrome. I think the crossorigin attribute is for something else. I did try using it and no luck. Worst case, I will do the testing you suggest by moving the landing page to root domain. I was hoping an answer here would save me the work.

Comment: Have you tried FF? From MDN link above: "Will Mozilla prefetch documents from a different host? Yes. There is no same-origin restriction for link prefetching. Limiting prefetching to only URLs from the the same server would not offer any increased browser security." This passage can be outdated, but still. It'll be good to know if they differ in their behavior with Chrome.

Comment: I tried but I wasn't able to disable service workers which seemed to be taking precedence over prefetch cache. I can give it another try though.

Comment: @Maros, somehow you don't own the code, or there was some technical issue?

Answer (score -1):

Adding `<link rel=prefetch>` to a web page tells the browser to download entire pages or some of the resources (like scripts or CSS files), that the user might need in the future. This can improve metrics like First Contentful Paint and Time to Interactive and can often make subsequent navigations appear to load instantly.

[image]

The prefetch hint consumes extra bytes for resources that are not immediately needed, so this technique needs to be applied thoughtfully; only prefetch resources when you are confident that users will need them. Consider not prefetching when users are on slow connections. You can detect that with the Network Information API.

There are different ways to determine which links to prefetch. The simplest one is to prefetch the first link or the first few links on the current page. There are also libraries that use more sophisticated approaches, explained later in this post-https://web.dev/link-prefetch/.

Comment: I was looking to get an explanation of why link prefetching is not speeding things up in my particular case. Is it because of subdomains, service workers or something else? If you look at my screenshots, you can see that the browser re-downloads the content despite prefetching.

Answer (score -1):

you should add  below code in case you are ont subdomain and you want resource from  domain

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://example.com">
```